# How can I exclude newlines in Scala RegexParsers matches?

Tags: regex, scala

I'd like to have something that matches basically anything to end-of-line of a multi-line string. Ideally something like this:

```
def almostAnything: Parser[String] = """[^\r\n]+""".r ^^ { _.toString.trim }
```

Problem is... this doesn't work.  It ignores the negated \n and just keeps matching away onto the next chunk of string after the \n.

Why is that, and how can I successfully match anything up to end-of-line (!= end-of-string)?

Comment: for your updated question: could you provide an input and output string as example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the parsers work, but the problem you're encountering here is not with your regular expression, but with the way `Regex` works.

By defaults, `Regex`s are anchored - they expect to match the entire string. If you want partial matches (and it seems that you do), you must unanchor them.

For example:

```
 val sameLine = """([^\r\n]+)""".r.unanchored

 "45ft\n  something" match {
   case sameLine(c) => Some(c)
   case _ => None
 }
```

This yields `Some(45ft)`.